# Sum up multiple values based off a single column

Tags: sql

For context, I work in transportation. Also, I apologize for a poor title - I'm not exactly sure how to summarize my issue.

I am currently editing an existing report which returns a drivers ID, their name, when they were hired, and the total amount of miles they have driven since they have started at the company. It was brought to my attention that drivers who move within the company are assigned a different driverID, which is not counted towards their total miles driven. Using an example provided to me, I was indeed able to confirm this scenario, as indicated below:

```
DriverCode   DriverName
-----------  ----------------
WETDE        Wethington,Dean
WETDEA       Wethington,Dean
```

This is the query that gets the above (example driver is hardcoded at the moment):

```
select mpp.mpp_id as DriverCode,
       mpp.mpp_lastfirst as DriverName
from manpowerprofile mpp
    outer apply (select top 1 mpp_id
                 from manpowerprofile) as id
where mpp_firstname = 'Dean'
    and mpp_lastname = 'Wethington'
```

This is the current query as it stands:

```
SELECT lh.lgh_driver1 as DriverCode
              ,m.mpp_lastfirst as DriverName
              ,m.mpp_hiredate as HireDate
              ,SUM(s.stp_lgh_mileage) as TotMiles
FROM stops s (nolock)
             INNER JOIN legheader lh (nolock) on lh.lgh_number = s.lgh_number
             INNER JOIN manpowerprofile m (nolock) on m.mpp_id = lh.lgh_driver1

            /* OUTER APPLY ( SELECT top 1 mpp_id
                           FROM manpowerprofile) as id */

WHERE m.mpp_terminationdt > GETDATE()
              AND m.mpp_id <> 'UNKNOWN'
              AND lh.lgh_outstatus = 'CMP'
GROUP BY lh.lgh_driver1, m.mpp_lastfirst, m.mpp_hiredate
    HAVING SUM(s.stp_lgh_mileage) > 850000
ORDER BY DriverCode DESC
```

What I'm looking to do is check to see if a name exists twice, and if it does, add both of those driver code's total miles together to return a single result for that individual driver. I'm a pretty novice SQL Developer still and have only now really started to delve into databases.

My current train of thought was to use an outer apply, but I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

Comment: If there ARE two drivers with the same name, what do you want in the `DriveCode` and `HireDate` columns?  The `MAX()` of each?  The values from the drive with the lowest `DriveCode`?  And why on earth are you using `NOLOCK`?  That's going to give bad results a lot of the time.

Comment: I guess I didn't think of that. I guess it would make sense to leave off the DriverCode, then.

Comment: This may create problems for different drivers with identical names, though. I think the root cause of the problem is changing the ID; it's not supposed to happen in a properly designed system.

Comment: No, it really shouldn't. We're actually in the process of telling the business not to do that for this reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, leaving off the driver code and hire date...
*(Because they could/would be different for the drivers being combined.)*

```
SELECT 
    m.mpp_lastfirst as DriverName
   ,SUM(s.stp_lgh_mileage) as TotMiles
FROM
    stops s (nolock)
INNER JOIN
    legheader lh (nolock)
        on lh.lgh_number = s.lgh_number
INNER JOIN
    manpowerprofile m (nolock)
        on m.mpp_id = lh.lgh_driver1
WHERE
        m.mpp_terminationdt > GETDATE()
    AND m.mpp_id <> 'UNKNOWN'
    AND lh.lgh_outstatus = 'CMP'
GROUP BY
    m.mpp_lastfirst
HAVING
    SUM(s.stp_lgh_mileage) > 850000
ORDER BY
    m.mpp_lastfirstDESC
```

Comment: That works great, thanks. In terms of the DriverCode, do you think it would be a good idea to have a column that would contain all of the driverID's associated with that driver?

Comment: No, I think ***not*** aggregating them in a report is a better idea.  Instead have another report that flags drivers potentially in need of reconciling, then have a process to correct the data *(so they have the same ID)*.  Then this report doesn't need to be aware of this at all.  ***This*** report should reflect what the data ***is***, not some whacky version of what ***maybe it should be***.

Comment: I'll bring that up to the rest of the business, because that seems like it would be a good idea. I wish I had more control over that aspect of the company - as it would make my life as a developer a hell of a lot easier. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Point out to the business that if this report does automated reconciliation, what about other reports?  They'll need updating, or something to communicate explicitly what the differences are.  It breaches the notion of a "single version of the truth".  However you go about it, something centralised should deal with this, so everything picks it up without the chance of it being forgotten or implemented differently.  (*Decouple responsibilities.*)